# Difference between marks and next multiple of 5 is less than 3 then round the marks to next multiple of 5. Marks below 50 will not be upgraded

Tags: c, arrays, loops

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n, i, out;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if( (arr[i] < 0) || (arr[i] > 100) )
            printf("Invalid");
        else if(arr[i] > 50)
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        else
        {
            if ( (arr[i] % 5 == 1) || (arr[i] % 5 == 2) )
            {
                out = ( arr[i]/5 + 1 * 5 );
                printf("%d", out);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Not getting errors but I don't get the required output.
Trying to solve in the array.
Eg:72 will be rounded but 48 will not be upgraded.
Marks below 0 and greater than 100 will be printed invalid.
The output format is to be in upgraded marks.

Comment: Please edit the heading and describe your problem in a short way. The current heading doesn't seems it's explaining your problem. Also, describe what values did you enter to the program.

Comment: Are you sure you about this? `int out=(arr[i]/5+1*5)`? Either you wanted 5 + 1*5 or (5 + 1 = 6) * 5.

Comment: Title is different than the code. What are you tryin to ask?

Comment: @RohanBari Assume ```int arr[3] = { 21, 22, 25};``` then ```out``` will be ```9 9 25``` & it is the correct output. Now, I don't understand what OP is asking? This code is working as it is meant to.

Comment: @lucas if it is int arr[3]={21,22,25} I need the output as 25,25,25 ie everything to be rounded to next multiple of 5 since differences between these numbers and next multiple of 5 is above 2....suppose if there was 23 or 24,it will not be upgraded because differences between these numbers and next multiple of 5 ie 25 is less than 3.

Comment: @RohanBari I hope u got the question

Comment: Indeed! I didn't understand anything except this line ```I need the output as 25,25,25 ie everything to be rounded to next multiple of 5.``` @Feriha I'll try to help you. But before anything you should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: wait before that the numbers below 50 will not be upgraded.The latter applies to all inputs above 50@lucas

Comment: Its a long question.I aint know how to ask since I am kinda new to stack.@lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program designed from beginning and I hope it meets your requirement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int size = 0;
    int *array;
    int expression = 0;

    printf("Array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Input value %d: ", (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] < 0 || array[i] > 100) {
            printf("Invalid.\n");
            break;
        } else if (array[i] < 50)
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        else {
            if (array[i] % 5 < 3)
                printf("%d ", array[i]);
            else {
                if (array[i] % 5 == 0)
                    expression = ((array[i] / 5) * 5);
                else
                    expression = ((array[i] / 5) * 5 + 5);

                printf("%d ", expression);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The conditions were mentioned:

1. Numbers lesser than `0` and greater than `100` are invalid.
2. The `50` and above numbers are incremented to the next multiple of 5
3. Those numbers whose remainders are lesser than or equal to 2 are not incremented, otherwise rounded to the next multiple of 5.

> **Sample Output:**

```
Array size: 3
Input value 1: 22 // not incremented (< 50)
Input value 2: 63 // incremented (remainder: 3 and above)
Input value 3: 78 // incremented
22 65 80
```

Comment: OP is asking the problem in ```C```.

Comment: I hope it runs but.....I have no idea about C++.I am kinda new to programming.I just started some basics in c...Could u please upload it in c?@RohanBari

Comment: @Feriha You may check it now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n, i, out;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];

    printf("Enter %d values for the array: ", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    printf("\nOutput:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if( (arr[i] < 0) || (arr[i] > 100) )
            printf("Invalid\n");
        else if(arr[i] > 50)
        {
            printf("%d > 50\n", arr[i]);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( (arr[i] % 5) != 0)
            {
                out = ( (arr[i]/5)*5 + 5 );
                printf("%d ", out);
            }
            else
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Before writing a program, think about how the user will interact with this? That's why I added those `printf` lines in the code. To round off to the next multiple of 5 you should take a look at `( (arr[i]/5)*5 + 5 )`. I assume you know about the operator precedence & associativity. It'll help you to understand and evaluate this line.
This `( (arr[i]/5)*5 + 5 )` will round off the value obtained by `arr[i]/5` to the next multiple of 5.

**Edit:** I added `continue;` statement in `else if(arr[i] > 50)` so that it will not round off if value is greater than 50.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I compiled your program but the output is not the expected one.If I input 22..it should not be upgraded since its less than 50 but in case if I input 63,77 etc I should get the next rounded multiple of 5....63--65 and 77--80@lucas

Comment: @Feriha try to explain your problem the best of you could.

Comment: @RohanBari Just giving an example:If I input 22..it should not be upgraded since its less than 50 but in case if I input 63,77 etc I should get the next rounded multiple of 5....63--65 and 77--80.And also any numbers whose difference between the number and next multiple of 5 is two or less than two ,it shall not be upgraded.Example 78,68 etc will not be upgraded

Comment: @Feriha Ah, this time I understood pretty much clearly. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @Lucas one problem. `int arr[n]`, many people who're not very much aware of dynamic array allocation mistakenly supposes this statement will create N elements for the array. Try to use a debugger and use a breakpoint in that syntax.

Comment: Bro @RohanBari ! If you don't know, it's allowed from C99/C11 and I also agree to have a dynamic memory allocation for arrays like this rather than going with what's written in the code.

Comment: In **ANSI C**, we must declare array dimensions using integer constants. But C99 permits declaration of array dimensions using integer variables or any valid integer expressions. The values of these variables can be specified just before they are used. aka ```Variable-Length Arrays```. @RohanBari